# Want to Change Settings in js while it crosses certain position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm creating a navbar & i'm using bootstrap for this.

i'm using padding top 60px while my nav is transparent

[image]

Here is my nav code

```
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
   padding-top: 60px;
 }
```

and my navbar-brand class

```
 .navbar-brand{
   padding-top:30px;
 }

now when the navbar scrolls > 100 it looks like this
```

[image]

Now i want to make it 30px when scroll > 100 Here is my js code

```
 var a = $(".navbar-default").offset().top;
 $(document).on('scroll', function() {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.navbar-default').addClass("scrolled");
    $(".navbar-default .navbar-brand").css({
        "color": "#a96258"
    });
 } 
 else {
    $('.navbar-default').removeClass("scrolled");
    $(".navbar-default .navbar-brand").css({
        "color": "#fff"
    });
  }
});
```

My scrolled Class

```
 .navbar-default.scrolled{
   background-color: #fff;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB9BE;
   box-shadow: 0,0,2px,#BBB9BE;
   color: #000;
   min-height: 80px;
 }
```

Comment: can you prepare a fiddle??

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching it to `window.scroll` as below:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.navbar-default').addClass("scrolled");
        $(".navbar-default .navbar-brand").css({
        "color": "#a96258"
    });
  } 
  else {
    $('.navbar-default').removeClass("scrolled");
    $(".navbar-default .navbar-brand").css({
        "color": "#fff"
    });
  }
});
```

Or Alternatively you can add an event listener as below

```
var element = $(".navbar-default");
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
     $(window).scrollTop() > 100 ? 
     $(element).addClass('scrolled',function(){
             $(".navbar-default .navbar-brand").css({
                    "color": "#a96258"
             });
     }) : 
     $(element).removeClass('scrolled',function(){
             $(".navbar-default .navbar-brand").css({
                    "color": "#fff"
             });
     });
});
```

Comment: This looks like a repetition of the code that was provided, just written a bit differently. Not an answer, even though the question itself is somewhat unclear.

Comment: @Shikkediel.. FYI there is slight difference between `document scroll` and `window scroll`..

Comment: What would that effectively be then?

Comment: @Shikkediel.. The `window` object is a top level client side object. There is nothing above the `window` object. A `window` object is created with each frame, thus main window is one frame. An html document is considered the `document`. `document` object is an object of the `window` object. So it's always good to use `window` to perform scroll or attach events for scroll!!

Comment: Nice quote but it says a bit further on : *To answer your question, There is No difference in the end result.*

Comment: I agree @Shikkediel.. But here we are talking about scroll and the same says _In general use document mainly to register events and use window to do things like scroll, scrollTop, and resize._!!! and I have also mentioned in my answer to try it not as perfect answer!!

Comment: Not arguing with that (I prefer using window as well), just discussing in general (getting 'warned' to not do so in the comments though, lol). Would be better if OP clarified his expectations.

Comment: Even me buddy!! It was a general discussion!! After all knowledge doubles when we share.. :) I Second your last point.. :)